# A lower bound for the difference between rationals and an irrational number on the real line

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

Let $S \subset \mathbb R$, and fix an $x \in S\backslash\mathbb Q$. Then is the following statement valid?

There exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\vert{x - y}\vert > \epsilon$ for all $y \in \mathbb Q \cap S$.

An obvious candidate for $\epsilon$ would be $\inf \{\vert x-y \vert : y \in \mathbb Q \cap S \}$. But can we show that this value is strictly positive?

Comment: You can find rational numbers that are arbitrarily close to your chosen irrational $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.  For a given irrational number (say $\pi$), it has a decimal expansion.  We have that the sequence of rational numbers $\lbrace x_n\rbrace =  (3,3.1,3.14,\dots)$ has the property that, for any $\epsilon>0$, that for all $n\geq N$ for some $N$ that $|\pi-x_n|<\epsilon$.  This argument can be repeated for any irrational number's decimal expansion.

The proof that the $N$ exists isn't that hard.  We have that for any $\epsilon>0$ that for some $k$ there is $10^{-k}<\epsilon$ (by the archimedean property).  So, for all $n\geq k$, we'll have the result.

Answer (score 0):

Note that while the other answer is technically correct, it doesn't address your question because there are no irrationals in $\{\pi_n\}$. In other words, there's no $x$ to choose.

It's a property of the rationals that you can approximate irrationals arbitrarily well. Take $S=\{e(1+(-1)^n)-2-\sum\limits_{1\le k\le n} 2/k! \big\vert n\in \mathbb{N}\}.$ We can only pick $x=2e-2$ (we get it when $n=0$, by definition of empty sum); on the other hand $\sum_{k\ge1} 2/k!=2e-2=x$, meaning that you can't find an $\varepsilon$ that works for all rational $y$ in $S$.